# What Kconfig file Represents?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I had written one driver for serial communication. Now I want to add it to my `linux kernel`. So for that I have to change `Kconfig` file in `drivers/usb/serial`.
I have rerffered `Kconfig` file in that. But I don't understand the names written after config, tristate etc.

What that names indicate? Where they belong or link(I don't find that particular name in that dedicatory)?

Comment: Your best bet is to start by reading the documentation available in the Linux kernel source in `Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. And i had read it. But it gives only information about attributes not the name written after that.
EXA.
config SERIAL_AMBA_PL010
tristate "ARM AMBA PL010 serial port support"

 depends on ARM_AMBA && (BROKEN || !ARCH_VERSATILE)
 select SERIAL_CORE
 help
   This selects the ARM(R) AMBA(R) PrimeCell PL010 UART.  If you have
   an Integrator/AP or Integrator/PP2 platform, or if you have a
   Cirrus Logic EP93xx CPU, say Y or M here.

   If unsure, say N.


what "ARM AMBA PL010 serial port support" indicate, if tristate indicates that perticular configure has three states (N,Y,M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name that you write after *tristate* (it is not always tristate), is just the name of the driver. To see it, try to use:

```
make ARCH=ARM menuconfig
```

Go into:

```
     -> Device Drivers
         -> Character devices
             -> Serial drivers
```

Here you can see the name *ARM AMBA PL010 serial port support* associated to the PL011 driver